# why after installing @auth0/angular-jwt, its module does not work?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am using angular 15.0 and installed @auth0/angular-jwt. when using it by import its module in the project, I encountered many errors, and I searched a lot and unfortunately, I did not find a suitable solution.
First, its module is not available in the node_modules folder, even in package.jason file:
[image]

```js
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^15.0.0",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.12.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.2.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^6.2.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^6.2.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.2.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jalali-moment": "^3.3.11",
    "jalali-ts": "^2.0.5",
    "material-icons": "^1.13.1",
    "ng-persian-datepicker": "^6.1.2",
    "ngx-mat-select-search": "^7.0.0",
    "ngx-print": "^1.3.1",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.12.0"
  },
```

Secondly, importing the JwtModule in the AppModule will result in the following error or warning:
[image]

[image]

the AppModule:

```js
import { JwtModule } from "@auth0/angular-jwt";
import {AuthGuard} from "../services";

export function tokenGetter() {
  return localStorage.getItem("jwt");
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
   ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
    JwtModule.forRoot({
      config:{
        tokenGetter: tokenGetter,
        whitelistedDomains: ["localhost:5001"],
        blacklistedRoutes: []
      }
    })
  ],
  providers: [
    ...
  ],
  exports: [
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
 
}
```

Where did I go wrong? please guide me.

Comment: The name of the property should be `allowedDomains` https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt/blob/main/API.md#alloweddomains-array

Comment: I tired already these suggestions but got the same errors.

Comment: Check other fields name as well. For example `blacklistedRoutes` should be `disallowedRoutes`

Comment: I tried it also, but I did not get the result and the same error is given. Of course, it's not an error, it's a kind of warning, because when I run the app, a tread dump occurs and is displayed in console the  Error: NG0203: inject() must be called from an injection context such as a constructor, a factory function, a field initializer, or a function used with `EnvironmentInjector#runInContext`. this error is for importing JwtModule, because when I remove it, the problem is solved. even I use stack trace, but it shows only this error and not its location.  this becomes a very big problem.